# How can I make a direct PHONE CALL in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-intent

I need to make a direct **Phone Call** in flutter but it's just opening the Phone app dialer.
No direct phone call is made.

In fact, I also tried with `url_launcher` package for this task but am getting the same result.

```dart
    _launchURL() async {
    SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.CallPhone)
        .then((state) async {
      if (state == PermissionStatus.authorized) {
        String a = Uri.encodeFull("#");
        String url = 'tel:*123' + a;
        if (await canLaunch(url)) {
          await launch(url);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
      }
    });}
```

Has anyone solved this before?

Comment: Yes, you want to make a call on an Android device--> it opens the dialer. You can not make a "silent" phone call on an Android device.

Comment: ACTION_CALL work in native android i think.

Comment: The ACTION_CALL action requires that you add the CALL_PHONE permission to your manifest file. Did you do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/ussd_service) author here.

Since Android API level 26, the method [sendUssdRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#sendUssdRequest(java.lang.String,%20android.telephony.TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) is exposed to make silent USSD requests.

I made a Flutter plugin called [ussd_service](https://pub.dev/packages/ussd_service) to be able to easily access it from dart in a Flutter application. It can be used in the following manner:

```dart
import 'package:ussd_service/ussd_service.dart';

makeMyRequest() async {
  int subscriptionId = 1; // sim card subscription Id
  String code = "*21#"; // ussd code payload
  try {
    String ussdSuccessMessage = await UssdService.makeRequest(subscriptionId, code);
    print("succes! message: $ussdSuccessMessage");
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print("error! code: ${e.code} - message: ${e.message}");
  }
};

makeMyRequest();
```

Hope this helps! Let me know on the [Github repo](https://github.com/vkammerer/ussd_service)'s issues if you have any issue with it.

Comment: This user (in question) seems to be intent on making phone calls. Evidence, he used `url_launcher` which doesn't do `ussd` either.

Comment: @MwamiTovi the String passed (`"tel:*123#"`) indicates that the intended action is to send a USSD request rather than launch a phone call. While it is possible to do it by popping up the dialer application, my reply explains how to do it in the background in Android.

Comment: @SifaturRahman this is because you need a `main` function entry point in dart. see https://pub.dev/packages/ussd_service#-example-tab- for a full working example

Answer (score 2):

You need to use URL encoding for special character.

Like this:

```
launch("tel:" + Uri.encodeComponent('*123#'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a plugin called [flutter_phone_direct_caller](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller) exactly for this purpose.

You can use it like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _callNumber,
        child: Text('Call Number'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_callNumber() async{
  const number = '08592119XXXX'; //set the number here
  bool res = await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(number);
}
```

Hopefully it can help someone.

Comment: The plugin(flutter_phone_direct_caller) remains undefined in flutter 1.20.4. i am not sure what is hapening

Answer (score 1):

Add these packages to your dependencies:

```
android_intent_plus: ^2.0.0
permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2
```

Import them in your .dart file:

```
import 'package:android_intent_plus/android_intent.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

Request for phone call permission in your `main()` function:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Permission.phone.request();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

And finally you can make direct phone calls like this:

```
AndroidIntent intent = const AndroidIntent(
  action: 'android.intent.action.CALL',
  data: 'tel:2125551212',
);
await intent.launch();
```